# Can obfuscation cause wrong methods to be called?

Tags: java, android, function, methods, obfuscation

I am working on an Android project where as soon as I enable obfuscation, a different method is called than intended.

IE, main Activity opens up and upon start calls Method A, which prints a Toast that says Method A. This is how it should normally run; however, when I make a release build, set minifyEnabled to true, and allow obfuscation, I run the same app and it now, upon start, calls Method B, which prints a Toast that says Method B.

I have no clue how this is happening, and since I am unable to read the logcat (As a release, I don't have this issue in the debug), I don't really know where to go from here.

Is it possible that obfuscation is changing my app structure so that a different method/ function is being called by mistake? Or is it more likely that the cause of the problem is something else?

-Sil

Comment: You can translate the stack trace back to its original symbols using a proguard tool called `retrace`.  You can also see how the symbols have been translated by looking at the generated mappings.txt.  But I have never heard of proguard making an obviously incorrect change like this.  It's used in countless applications and you'd think something this obvious would render it useless.

Comment: Thanks Doug, the retrace tool sounds useful, I'll follow that for a bit to see if it leads to more answers

Comment: It can happen if you obfuscate libraries and not just the final application. However, it will usually not compile at all.

Comment: @Sten, that's entirely possible what is happening here. I am using a few libraries (IE Gson), and although I am following their requirements for labeling them in the proguard file, I could see how this could be the culprit.

Comment: Enable minify in debug build type and see what's going on in logcat/debugger

Comment: I've seen issues like this if you subclass one of your application classes in your androidTest src directory (as is often done when mocking out certain pieces of functionality) and you don't properly configure Proguard to apply the mapping from the application to your test APK.  This results in the application class's method being called rather than the version that you created for your tests.  If you could post more details about your specific problem, that may help in coming up with an answer.

Comment: @Than, I am unable to find out how to do that. I have a debug tag within the buildtypes of the build.gradle file (         debug {
            minifyEnabled true; 
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } ), but it is not working and is still running the app without obfuscation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. Obfuscation will neither change your app's structure, nor  result in wrong methods being called. Almost all popular apps in the Play Store are encrypted / obfuscated.

Comment: However, Java reflection mechanism might be a bit problematic in matter of obfuscation.